# Concurrency during initramfs

Tags: linux, multithreading, linux-kernel, boot, bootloader

There's a (set of) task(s) that I'd like to run as soon as absolutely possible when my machine boots. This task involves polling a hardware character device and buffering the frames until the rest of the system comes online.

After doing some research, one nice solution seems to be to include the appropriate driver along with the binary that does the buffering in a initramfs image. When the system has booted properly, the buffered frames gets written to some file and the RAM reserved for buffering frames gets released.

But I'm wondering, can I run programs concurrently this early in boot? I mean, can I make it so that the frame buffering binary runs in its own thread, occupying its own piece of RAM, while the rest of the system boots?

If the answer is "no", then what is the earliest point in the boot process at which concurrency is supported?

Comment: Well earliest point is in kernel module itself, where the module is built into kernel image.

Comment: Programs cannot execute until userspace is active, which means that the kernel has completed its boot phase, and the init program has started.  It doesn't matter whether you use initramfs or a root filesystem on a nonvolatile medium, i.e. your title makes no sense